# Sort the asp.net gridview on a bound column in the aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I need to sort the rows in the asp:gridView in the aspx page on a field named LastName.

I bind the grid using a datatable in C#. I do not use the datasource in the aspx file.

Giving the SortExpression in the grid doesn't work.

Please can anyone direct me how to achieve this?

I've done this till now but it doesnt seem to sort

```
           <asp:GridView ID="gdPlayersList" runat="server" AllowSorting="true"  
              AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#F9F9F9" 
              Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Bold="False"            
              DataKeyNames="PlayerId,CasinoId"
              HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray"
              HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" RowStyle-BorderColor="#666666" 
              RowStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" RowStyle-BorderWidth="1px" 
              RowStyle-ForeColor="#666666"    OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound"  
              OnSorting="Grid_Onsorting"
              EmptyDataText="No records found" >
             <Columns>   
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name"  DataField="LastName" 
                  SortExpression="LastName"/>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date opened"   DataField="DateOpened" 
                  DataFormatString="{0:mm/dd/YYYY}" HtmlEncode="false" 
                  NullDisplayText="1/1/0001" />

        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>   

  C# code:

    protected void Grid_Onsorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable sourceTable = gdPlayersList.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataView view = new DataView(sourceTable);

        view.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
        this.ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";


    }

   protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
   ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look into [GridView.Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) Event?

Handle the `_Sorting` event, reassign and then `DataBind()`.

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
gv.DataSource = dt;
gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable tab = DataGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
tab.DefaultView.Sort = columnName + " " + sortOrder;
tab = tab.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

In the example above `tab` will be sorted

Comment: Thanks ! This sorts for one column. What if i need to give a windows like functionality? What do i need to do?

Comment: it'll sort one column but whole grid will be sorted on the basis of that column. like in Details View in Explorer.

Comment: After Sorting the table from above method you have to assigned the new table to grid & call Rebind function.